# Chrome-Extension: callback content.js from popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating this chrome extension that:

1) creates a custom button into the current page's DOM **(works)**

2) when the user clicks the button a HTML page with some input fields comes up **(works)**

3) The fields have pre-populated values from content.js **(works)**

4) When the user clicks On the Close button inside the form I would like to call 
a function in content.js that alerts the new values the user input. **(doesn't work)**

Here is my code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                CONTENT.js file   
//         - called every time a page is being loaded
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------




//------------------- Create the Custom Button-------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");         
btn.id= "myButton";
btn.name="myButton"; 
btn.addEventListener("click", popUpWindow);                              
document.getElementsByClassName("text1")[0].appendChild(btn);   


//------------------Init field Variables--------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var lastname ="Test";
var firstname = "Test1";
var myWindow;



//------------------Create a new Popup window-----------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function popUpWindow()
{

// send message to backgorund
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  from:       'content',
  subject:    'showPageAction',    
  firstname:   firstname,
  lastname:    lastname, 
});

var url = chrome.extension.getURL("window-child.html");
myWindow =window.open(url,"_blank", "width=400,height=300,0,status=0");

//call Close() function when the button "Close" is pressed
myWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
myWindow.document.getElementById('Close').onclick=Close;
});

}

//the close function that should be called
function Close()
{

// the updated "firstname" value that should be alerted
    alert(localStorage.firstname);

}
```

background.js

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                               BACKGROUND.js file
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//get the message from content.js and update the localStorage
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {

  // First, validate the message's structure
  if ((msg.from === 'content') && (msg.subject === 'showPageAction')) {

    localStorage["firstname"]=msg.firstname;
     localStorage["lastname"]=msg.lastname;

    // Enable the page-action for the requesting tab
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);

  }
});
```

Here is popup.js

```
// Update the relevant fields with the new data
function setDOMInfo(info) {

  document.getElementById('firstname').value      = localStorage["firstname"];
  document.getElementById('lastname').value       = localStorage["lastname"];
}

// Once the DOM is ready...
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // ...query for the active tab...
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function (tabs) { 
    // ...and send a request for the DOM info...
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        {from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo'},
        // ...also specifying a callback to be called 
        //    from the receiving end (content script)
        setDOMInfo);
  });

});


function Close() {
    alert("Closed");
  chrome.storage.local.firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    window.close();
   }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("Close").addEventListener("click", Close);

});
```

and this is the HTML popup page( window-child.html)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>   
   <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">

    </script> 
    <style> 
      #leadinformation { text-align: left; font: 12px; position :absolute; padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;} 
      button { position: relative; top: 30%;  font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;background-image: webkit-linear-gradient(top, #287bbc 0%,#23639a 100%);background-color: #287bbc; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; boder-color: #1b5480; width: 160px; height: 35px;} 
      #titleParagraph {font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;} 
    </style>  
  </head> 
   <body> 


    <form> 
     <div id="leadinformation"> 
      <p id="titleParagraph">You are about to create a new Lead:</p> 
        First Name.....   <input type="text" id="firstname" value= window.openerfirstname >   <br> 
        Last Name.....   <input type="text" id="lastname" value= lastname >   <br> 
      <div> 

        <button id="Accept"  >Accept</button> 
        <button id="Close" >Close</button> 
       </form> 
     </div> 
    </body> 
   </html>
```

I hope that I stated clear enough what my code does and what I want to achieve. I struggled so much much in getting this done without any success. Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated.

I tried:

- chrome.storage.local.sync inside the popup.js but the values weren't saved in the content.js
- I tried chrome cross-origin messaging via postMessage  between popup.js and content.js but with no luck so far, I might be doing something wrong.
- I tried cross object post message but I was not sure how to proceed with it

**To summarize: I have a button --> I click the button --> a popup page comes up --> User inputs values and pressed Close Button --> the Close() function from content.js should be called where the new values should be alerted**

Comment: That's a different document, you can't call javascript functions directly across different windows! Post the messaging code you've used.

Comment: well I was thinking of sending a message back to background.js and from background to content.js. with something like :  `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "from background to content"}, function(response) {} }); ` .  In therms of the cross object post messaging code that I used I don't have it anymore, because I changed alot the files, but it didn;t work probably because I didn't use it properly. Would you be able to give me a sample how to use it better?

Comment: There are lots of samples you can find using google. Also there's probably was just a minor easily fixable flaw in your code...

Comment: Yes I know, I tried so many examples but nothing works for some reason, I've been experiencing this problem for like 4 days now, and I can't get rid of it. My brain is about to collapse soon if I don't solve it :(

Comment: So you are definitely 100% certain you can;t use chrome.tabs.sendMessage if the there are multiple windows opened at the same time. and that is should be done using  postMessage instead

Comment: You can't use `chrome.tabs` API inside the script of a normal HTML page such as that `window-child`. You **can** use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

Comment: @wOxxOm would it be possible to give a complete answer, related to my issue?

Comment: If "complete" means implementing the thing myself then maybe later or someone else will, as so far it doesn't seem trivial mostly because I'll have to understand your code and what it does exactly. I would prefer you read that link about the extension architecture and check out [the official samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will start reading through the extension architecture notes